# Rails 4 - Is there a performance win between using self. vs Model call in after_create callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create 10 prizes on the prize table.

**Is there a performance difference or any performance-related (like garbage colleciton maybe) that would help me decide between a and B**

**A**

```
after_create :create_prizes

 def create_prizes
   300000.times do
      prizes = self.prizes.create(:deal_id => self.id, :admin_user_id => self.admin_user_id)
    end
 end
```

**B**

after_create :create_prizes

```
 def create_prizes
  300000.times do
    prizes = Prize.create(:deal_id => self.id, :admin_user_id => self.admin_user_id)
  end
end
```

**B**

Note that when the Admin creates a deal, it will create a very large number of prizes (up to 300,000).

Thanks for any help,

Mathieu

Comment: There is no need to call save after create because create also saves the object to db. Also, when calling create or build on associated model (first example) you dont need to provide id of the parent so you can remove deal_id in first example

Comment: thanks will edit question remain true between self and Prizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option B should be slightly faster as AR does't need to traverse the relations to find the foreign key. However, inserting 300,000 records will be slow either way.

Consider generating a SQL INSERT statement or passing an array to create.

```
Prize.create([{deal_id: 1}, {deal_id: 2}])
```

https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Comment: thanks, I have to say I am used as a rookie more to active Record. what would be the SQL insert query code you talk about ?

Comment: I added a link that covers some options including that one.

Comment: I indeed needed to optimize performance if inserting 300K rows. I could not replicate this guy's method (option 2: raw sql with transactions) for Postgresql. I added a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327882/rails-4-postgresql-insert-data-on-a-table-based-on-another-table-data-after