# Rails 4 / postgresql - insert data on a table based on another table data (after_create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create prizes on the DealPrize table.

Deal and DealPrize have a belong to/has_many relations: a Deal has many Deal prizes and a Dealprize belongs to a Deal.

It works like this: inside Deal, I have a column 'prize-number' and I use an after_create so that evetytime the amdin creates a new deal, the app takes this prize_number column, and create this volume of prizes (inserting as many rows as necessary) inside the DealPrize table.

For performance sake as the number of prizes can be > 500,000 and in order to optimize the INSERT.

I found https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/: I opted foe the option 2 (raw SQL and usi_ng 'transactions'). Indeed the most efficient way (option  3: ' A single mass insert') is not easily available in piostgresql (the guy gives exmaples of SQL) and would be too dificult for mee a(it involves some COPY commands...).

So here is my code before optimizing (it works)

**models/deals.rb**

```
after_create :create_deal_prizes

def create_deal_prizes
      self.prizes_number.times do
        prizes = DealPrize.create(:deal_id => self.id, :admin_user_id => self.admin_user_id)
        prizes.save
      end
    end
```

**So I fail to apply option 2 (raw SQL with transaction) in PostgreSQL like [this guy for SQL](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/)**

Here' what I tried:

**models/deals.rb**

```
after_create :create_deal_prizes

def create_deal_prizes
      Deal.transaction do
        self.prizes_number.times do |i|
          DealPrize.connection.execute "INSERT INTO ‘deal_prizes’ (deal_id) values (self.deal.id)"
        end
      end
    end
```

But it fails and I get the error:

```
ERROR: relation "‘deal_prizes’" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO ‘click_win_throbbers’ (deal_id)
```

By the way, I also tried with INSERT INTO ‘dealprizes’, INSERT INTO ‘DealPrize’ it does not work either.

How to do this with PostgreSQL?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**
I tried

```
  def create_deal_prizes


  Deal.transaction do
    values = (0..prize_number).to_a.map{|x| "(#{x}),"}.join.chomp(",")

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values ( (#{values}), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13'), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13') )"
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: column "deal_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
PG::SyntaxError - ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: ...id, created_at, updated_at) values ( (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)..
```

.

Besides the deal_id that must be put into each row of new deal_prizes is the same: it's always the id of this single game: i don't won't each row of deal_prizes to have different deal_id (like here (1), (2)...

Here's the raw SQL

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "deals" INNER JOIN "friendly_id_slugs" ON "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = "deals"."id" AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = $1 WHERE ("deals"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND ("friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = 'Deal' AND "friendly_id_slugs"."slug" = 'zazzaza') LIMIT 1  [["sluggable_type", "Deal"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "deals" ("deal_main_goal", "deal_population_target_age", "deal_population_target_egroup", "deal_campaign_code", "country", "title", "description", "twitter_msg", "image_url", "deal_project_management_url", "client_contact_point_name", "client_contact_point_profile_url", "hp_image_alt", "rules_url", "deal_population_target_gender", "contact_for_prizes_full_name", "contact_for_prizes_email", "contact_for_prizes_how_to_contact_details", "contact_for_prizes_crm_profile_url", "click_to_win_throbber_per_deal_qty", "admin_user_id", "slug", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24) RETURNING "id"  [["deal_main_goal", "{}"], ["deal_population_target_age", "{}"], ["deal_population_target_egroup", "{}"], ["deal_campaign_code", ""], ["country", "Armenia"], ["title", "zazzaza"], ["description", ""], ["twitter_msg", ""], ["image_url", ""], ["deal_project_management_url", ""], ["client_contact_point_name", ""], ["client_contact_point_profile_url", ""], ["hp_image_alt", ""], ["rules_url", ""], ["deal_population_target_gender", ""], ["contact_for_prizes_full_name", ""], ["contact_for_prizes_email", ""], ["contact_for_prizes_how_to_contact_details", ""], ["contact_for_prizes_crm_profile_url", ""], ["prize_number", 7], ["admin_user_id", 1], ["slug", "zazzaza"], ["created_at", "2015-09-04 21:21:41.157857"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-04 21:21:41.157857"]]
   (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values ( ((0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13'), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13') )
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "deal_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
LINE 1: ...obbers (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values ( ((0),(1),(...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
: INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, created_at, updated_at) values ( ((0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13'), ('2009-01-23 20:21:13') )
   (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 605ms

PG::DatatypeMismatch - ERROR:  column "deal_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
```

Comment: no need to use self.

Comment: INSERT INTO deal_prizes .... #should work. just try wihout any backticks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have typo in your code. Connection should be of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` but you wrote `DealPrize.connection.execute`.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute "sql query"
```

Try change your code like

```
after_create :create_deal_prizes

def create_deal_prizes
  Deal.transaction do
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    self.prizes_number.times do |i|
      connection.execute "INSERT INTO ‘deal_prizes’ (deal_id) values (self.deal.id)"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi, will try it now sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

how about making some performance. instead of executing n-times raw SQL you can just make one long query. thanks to @Dipak for finding the typo

```
after_create :create_deal_prizes

def create_deal_prizes
  Deal.transaction do
    values = (0..prizes_number).to_a.map{|x| "(#{x}),"}.join.chomp(",")

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id) values #{values}"
  end
end
```

thats giving me

```
"INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id) values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50)"
```

Comment: I had a problem as I needed to add two other attributes and an erro => see my question edit

Comment: pls post the rails-log-sql when rails is inserting something

Comment: just put it in my EDIt

Comment: youre sql is totally off. in my sql there is nothing about timestamps. also i asked you to put the rails-sql for insert, i.e prizes.create, to see how the rails sql looks like

Comment: if i don't add created_at and updated_at I get this error "ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint so I need to add them like you can see in my question EDIT

Comment: Just added the whole rails-sql, sorry postgresql rookie here

Comment: you drive me nutz. why can't you just post what rails is doing if you insert a deal prize? like DealPrize.create price: 1000

Comment: Forget it, tx anyway, don't like your tone. thanks to remain respectful. Sorry if I can't keep up with you./

Comment: and please specify again the hole relation and why a deal need 500 deal-prizes without special values in there (just 500 times the same record?)

Comment: yes. so when I create anew game (say Rails attributes the id= 67), then I want to send via a after_create to the DealPrizes table 120,00 new rows (=deal.prize_number) where for each of them has inside the Deal_id column the value 67. that's it.

Comment: I need to send along deal_id, the attributes created_at and updated_at as Rails tell me they're compulsory

Comment: Actually, ALL I need is already on my question: check the first block of code : it is WORKING and what it does answers your question. But I want to optimize when inserting 120,000 rows, that's why I asked for help to implement advanced stuff like transactions.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id) value (67)"

does that work or still mysql error?